# Why is my static object undefined in JavaScript?

Tags: node.js, popper.js

I'm using the following library in Node.js:

https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html

My code is as follows:

```
const Popper = require("popper.js");
Popper.Defaults.modifiers.computeStyle.gpuAcceleration = false;
```

I get the error 'Cannot read property 'modifiers' of undefined'.

Why is Popper.Defaults undefined when it is a static property and how can I fix the error?

Comment: Your code works without errors. I did `npm i popper.js` and then executed these lines in node console, `Defaults` was not `undefined`. Did you install the package correctly?

Comment: You need to use 'options' argument to change Defaults. https://popper.js.org/popper-documentation.html#Popper.Defaults